# Override default styles to center Avada portfolio grid

Tags: css, grid

I'm looking for some advanced CSS help here in order to center the portfolio items located on this page [https://elysewalkerinteriors.com/interior-design-oakville/][1]

As you can see, they all appear to skew to the left. The underlying `<article>` (portfolio items) are all absolutely positioned with the parent container set to `position: relative`.

I had to add a custom style to make each column width 32% (33% caused the column layout to break from 3 columns to 2, leaving a big white gap on the right side).

I'm curious how one might approach this situation and center the portfolio items on the page.

Thank you
[1]: [https://elysewalkerinteriors.com/interior-design-oakville/#:~:text=Check%20Out%20Some%20Of%20Our%20Latest%20Designs](https://elysewalkerinteriors.com/interior-design-oakville/#:%7E:text=Check%20Out%20Some%20Of%20Our%20Latest%20Designs)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [CSS Grid:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid)

> A CSS grid is defined using the grid value of the display property; you can define columns and rows on your grid using the grid-template-rows and grid-template-columns properties.

```css
section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}

article {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
  <article><p>Test</p></article>
</section>
```